# Excel SUMIFS not working on a certain type of array

Tags: arrays, excel, sumifs

I can't find a way to paste the file I'm working on but basically, I downloaded the template here:

https://templates.office.com/en-us/simple-loan-calculator-and-amortization-table-tm16400462

and I'm trying to run a calc on another sheet which sums total interest paid in a given year as calculated in this sheet (i.e. between 1/1/ and 12/31 for a given year), where the year is a dynamic input cell.

So I was basically trying to use SUMIFS, but for some reason, the formula can't recognize the date criteria in column C.

Any suggestions?

Comment: SUMIFS definitely works for me with that template, for example: `=SUMIFS(D:D,C:C,">="&DATE(2021,1,1))`. Please create a [reprex] with the formula you are trying.

Comment: " can't recognize the date criteria in column C. ".. how does your formula n data looks like?